# Elastic Query for full text search

Tags: elasticsearch

Created an index using elastic POST request (there will be multiple records)

```
POST /rewards/deals/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{
    "deal_id":25, 
    "title": "Deal 1 Title", 
    "deal_subtitle":"Deal 1 subtitle - Amazing deal 20% off",
    "header_title":"Never before deal", 
    "header_subtitle":"This is available as an amazing deal you can use.", 
    "categories":[
    {"categoryId":32, "categoryName":"Treats!"},
    {"categoryId":31, "categoryName":"Travel & Transportation"}],
    "stores_list": [{"storeId":524, "storeName":"Awesome store", "geoX":"", "geoY":"", "postalCode":"417392"}], 
    "merchant_name": "Merchant Name", 
    "id": 1, 
    "merchant_id": 137, 
    "startEnd":"2018-11-16 00:00:00", 
    "endDate":"2018-11-30 00:00:00"
}
```

wrote the query to perform full-text search

```
GET /rewards/deals/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "treat",
      "fields": ["title^10", "deal_subtitle^10", "header_subtitle^5", "header_title^5", "categories.categoryName^3", "stores_list.storeName^3", "stores_list.postalCode^3", "merchant_name^10"]
    }
  }
}
```

But I do not get any data in response for "treat" also treat(stemmed from treats) is available in categories.categoryName. Can someone please assist.
When I search "treats" I get the response. how can I get a response for words that begin with the search keyword.

Comment: Try to use the _analyze endpoint. See if it's analyzed propelry

Comment: oh got it to work, just needed to add the "type":"phrase_prefix" to my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by just adding a "type" to the existing query

```
GET /rewards/deals/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "treat",
      "type":"phrase_prefix",
      "fields": ["title^10", "deal_subtitle^10", "header_subtitle^5", "header_title^5", "categories.categoryName^3", "stores_list.storeName^3", "stores_list.postalCode^3", "merchant_name^10"]
    }
  }
}
```